# Disable GTK 3 Client Side Decorations on Windows

Tags: windows, gtk

GnuCash has enabled GTK Client Side Decorations in their latest update and with the win32 theme it causes the application to not match the native title bar look and it behaves poorly (show window contents while dragging doesn't work and window snapping doesn't work some of the time).

Is there any way through configuration files to globally disable the client side decorations for GTK3 applications on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an environment variable named `GTK_CSD` with value `0` will disable GTK 3 client side decorations.